# optimize a c code on nested loop

Tags: c, performance, optimization, for-loop

I have the following code

```
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
  for(j=0;j<16;j++)
  {
     in=(i+u*j+rl+rc)&15;
     jn=(v*i+(u*v+1)*j+rc)&15;
     x1[i*16+j]=x2[in*16+jn];
   }
```

some notes:

1. `rl`,`rc`,`u`, and `v` are randome values range from 0 to 15
2. `x1` and `x2` are arrays of 256 values, the range of each array value is between 0 and 255
3. if I want to implement this code using lookup table is need 16MB and this large memory

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Homework? If not, don't bother - a modern compiler will figure this out. Keep the code readable until you profile it when you have free time or suspect performance issues. It is called source code because humans read it.

Comment: Why closing? I think it's a valid question not very well asked. There's a room for optimization here, I think. Some combination of LUT and smarter math. Have not yet come up with the solution though.

Comment: In general, it makes no sense to manually optimize anything without in-depth knowledge of the underlying hardware. In the case of for loops, it especially doesn't make any sense without in-depth knowledge of the cache memory hardware, if present on the specific system.

Comment: ...also, if you repeatedly choose variable names with 1-2 obscure letters and have a habit of writing 5 or more operators on the same line, and write bit masks with decimal notation, then program performance is the least one of your problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some idea you could try:

You could build a look-up table for all combinations of `u` and `v`, that would require only 64k of memory. `rl` and `rc` work as constant offsets horizontally and vertically (they could be moved to last statement and don't have to participate in the calculation of `in` and `jn`).  That would reduce amount of math you have to do.

Like with any other performance optimizations you first of need to see if this is really the bottleneck. It could be that memory is much slower and introducing large look-up table would only slow things down.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one idea:

Try to extract parts of the calculation that don't change to outside at least the inner loop. For example, `i + rl + rc` from the `in` calculation doesn't need to be inside the loop. Once you have that, you realize that the value of `in` increases by `u` every iteration, modulo 16 of course. So instead of doing a multiplication, you can do an addition.

The `jn` calculation also has quote a few things you can extract.

Of course, this is assuming that you actually know this to be a performance bottleneck (profile it!) and the compiler isn't smart enough to do such an optimization for your. When in doubt, inspect the assembly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compiler would do that for you.

Comment: It might - or it might not. I was tempted to say that it would, but it sounds like the poster works in some embedded system, and I don't trust compilers for those.

Comment: I'm pretty sure than even a compiler for the most low-end microcontrollers will do that optimization. The result of `i + rl + rc` will be temporarily placed in a register or on the stack. But of course, this is yet another example of why _it doesn't make sense to manually optimize code without knowing anything about the intended hardware_.